# How to read data from slave device using i2c?

Tags: stm32, i2c, hal-library

I am trying to read cell voltage 1 value with CRC over i2c. I am using bq76942 EVM(BMS) module as my slave device. Following is the code I am using :

[image]

The CRC I am getting through response is 0x45.

But, the correct CRC value is 0x2B according to the CRC function.

[image]

For the second byte of data, the response value is 0x23 which is correct. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

> [Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76942.pdf?ts=1600108786849&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ76942) Please see page number 76.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text-based code, we can't copy/paste it to give you a corrected version, or to try it for ourselves.

Comment: Please edit to the question what is the slave device. It is hard to know if you are using correct I2C transactions without looking at the slave datasheet.

Comment: How to read data from slave over i2c using HAL_I2C_Master_Sequential_Receive_IT?

Comment: I think by using repeated start condition will solve my problem? My slave address is 0x08(7 bit address) .

Comment: Please delete either this question or the one posted on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63886716/how-to-read-data-from-slave-device-using-i2c).

Comment: CRC implementation is correct. You can also use the online CRC calculator. According to the bq76942 datasheet. In a single-byte read transaction, the CRC is calculated beginning at the first start, so will include the slave
address, the register address, then the slave address with read bit set, then the data byte.   [0x10, 0x14, 0x11, 0x01]

Comment: @Codo Yes, I am getting correct data other than CRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the way the I2C function is doing a start, stop and then start. If you use a repeated start like in the Software Development guide app note (https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sluaa11/sluaa11.pdf) then the CRC would include the bytes for the first write [0x10 0x14 0x11 0x01]. However, since you are doing a stop and then a start, it seems like it will calculate CRC only on the 2nd transaction [0x11 0x01].

In ST you can use

> HAL_I2C_Master_Sequential_Transmit_IT(); instead of
> HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit()

Code :

```
 char cmd=0x14; 
 char readbuf[4]={0,0,0,0};

 HAL_I2C_Master_Sequential_Transmit_IT(&hi2c1, 0x08 << 1, &cmd, 1, I2C_FIRST_FRAME);
 while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY);
 
 HAL_I2C_Master_Sequential_Receive_IT(&hi2c1, 0x08 << 1, readbuf, 4, I2C_LAST_FRAME);
 while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY);
```